Cant boot my Dell Latitude E5450 LAPTOP
I have a Dell Latitude E5450 Laptop.  When I switch on the laptop it reads "No Boot Device Found. Press any key to reboot the machine"  Once I press any key the screen goes blank and then the message returns again.

First of all check UEFI settings - Boot menu and adjust accordingly. If it doesn't work then likely the drive failed. Either way this is unanswerable without a lot more details.

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

That message is pretty clear and tells you what the problem is: the system cannot find the storage drive/HDD/SSD. This means the drive is failed, failing, or it missing boot information. Did you do any research on this prior to asking here, or did you try anything?
